# PHP/HTML create file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to have my scripts

- Receive suggestions
- Create file with suggestions named at date and time accurate to second

The problem that is occurring is that the file is create but contains no data.

**HTML Button**

```
<form action="suggestions.php" action="POST">
Suggest some content for this page: <input type="text" name="suggestion"></br>
</br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$filename = date('Format String');
$Content = $_POST["suggestion"];
file_put_contents('./suggestions/'.$filename, $Content);

?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple HTML typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the action attribute twice

```
<form action="suggestions.php" action="POST">
```

you surely meant the method attribute:

```
<form action="suggestions.php" method="POST">
```

that would have caused the form to be sent as `GET` and you POST vars to be empty

Answer (score 0):

in your HTML `form` you've made a typo error

`<form action="suggestions.php" action="POST">`

you need to change `action` to `method` here:

`<form action="suggestions.php" method="POST">`

Comment: Not true, default method is GET.